# GitHub folders have a white arrow on them

Tags: git, github

I have recently pushed to github, and see a white arrow on one of my folders.

[image]

and when i click on the folder, it does not open it. On my local machine, it has contents, but in github i cannot access them. What does this mean?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

### Symptom

Check if locally you have a `.git/` sub-folder under that folder.

### Cause

That would mean the folder (locally) is a **nested Git repository**, whose tree SHA1 is recorded as a "gitlink" (gray folder with straight white arrow)

What you would then see on GitHub is that [**gitlink**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fast-import#Documentation/git-fast-import.txt-Inlinedataformat): SHA-1 of the object refers to a commit in another repository, represented by an empty folder name. It is a nested Git repository.

If you see a `folder @ xxx`, then it is a [submodule entry](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitsubmodules#_description), meaning your own repository has a `.gitmodules` in it, which records, in addition of the gitlink, the actual URL of the remote repository.
It represents the object name of the commit that the super-project expects the nested submodule's working directory to be at.

In both cases (white arrow with a folder name, or white arrow with `folder @ xxx`, folder name *and* version), it is a Gitlink represented a nested Git repository: a placeholder for another Git repository, hence an empty folder. But in the second case, that empty folder would be referenced/visible in a special `.gitmodules` file.

---

### Solution (to remove the white arrow)

In order to restore that folder content:

#### submodule:

A [`git clone --recurse-submodules`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitsubmodules#_description) would restore the content of that submodule in your local repository (as opposed to a nested Git repo, where its URL is *not* recorded, and the content of the folder would remain empty)

The white arrow would remain on the remote repository, with `folder @ version` displaying what SHA1 of the submodule repository is referenced by your project.

#### Nested Git repository:

Alternatively, you could, if you don't care about the history of that folder, delete locally its `.git` subfolder (assuming it is *not* a submodule, meaning it is not referenced in a `.gitmodules` file in your main repository), add, commit and push.
The white arrow would then disappear, and you would be able to access that folder content on GitHub.

Then you would need to delete the gitlink entry:

```
git rm --cache client_folder 
# without a trailing slash: 
# not client_folder/ but client_folder
```

Finally, you can add, commit and push that folder content.

Comment: I'm facing this issue as well. used create-react-app inside node server folder to create client boiler plate. It has right arrow and adding recursively doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @deechris27 "addling recursively"? do you mean "cloning recursively"? Does your main repo has a `.gitmodules`?

Comment: yeahh... there is no ".gitmodules"  just the ".git" hidden folder. I deleted the ".git" that was inside the client folder and did a "git add ./client_folder" but still the right arrow is there.

Comment: That is because you need frst to do `git rm --cached client_folder` (without a trailing slash: not `client_folder/` but `client_folder`). Then, and only then you can add, commit and push.

Comment: @deechris27 Well done! I mentioned it recently in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62255502/6309

Answer (score 86):

The arrow may mean that is a submodule.

You could try:

```
git add yourfolder
```

If that results in an error like:

```
xxx submodule xxx
```

appears, you may try this:

```
git rm --cached yourfolder
```

Then, you could successfully run:

```
git add yourfolder
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `git rm --cached gitbook` ?

Comment: @Sterling this command will delete gitbook from local repo , you do this , when you make minor changes ,for example delete a file , that is already cached on local repo , but "git" sees no different between your local repo and current directory, so you go and delete the cached folder from repo , then u add it again .

Comment: It worked! I had to replace `gitbook` with my folder name

Comment: git add did not give me an error, yet git rm --cached followed by git add was still effective in fixing my problem.  I think my submodule was in a half-removed state.

Answer (score 11):

On your machine, if you navigated to the directory with the arrow and tried to view hidden files, you'd see a `.git` folder, indicating that it is a repository. This means that it is a repo contained inside the outer repo that you had pushed to GitHub.

The easiest way to get rid of the arrow and start seeing your files properly (in my opinion) is by deleting the `.git` folder. That way, it ceases to become a git repo and is a regular folder once more.

Now when you push to GitHub, you can normally access the folder and view all its contents.

Comment: Solved it and now understand it.
Delete the git files in that folder, 
git rm --cached folder_name, 
git add folder_name. 

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

In my case:

```
git rm --cached portal

ls 

git status

git add --all

...
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you want to remove a submodule from the git config files, Follow this, remember that if you DON'T want to delete the local directory of that submodule, DON'T do Step X:

Delete the relevant section from the .gitmodules file.

Stage the .gitmodules changes git add .gitmodules

Delete the relevant section from .git/config.

Run git rm --cached path_to_submodule (no trailing slash).

Run rm -rf .git/modules/path_to_submodule (no trailing slash).

Commit git commit -m "Removed submodule "

(Risky)Step X :- Delete the now untracked submodule files rm -rf path_to_submodule

Answer (score 5):

it worked, I followed these steps

1. remove it by git rm --cached folder-name
2. git add folder-name

that is it.

Comment: This has already been suggested by several existing answers ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63068443/3025856)), but with less explanation and context. Before answering questions on Stack Overflow, be certain to read the existing answers to ensure your suggestion hasn't already been proposed. If it has, please don't repeat the answer.

Comment: @JeremyCaney its not that serious bruh. This is why this site is 

Answer (score 3):

for me, the history of changes in the subfolders were no longer important

**start by removing .git from the subfolder**

```
git rm --cached myfolder

git add myfolder

git commit -m "making myfolder available"

git push
```

Answer (score 3):

It's due to the .git file in some of your subfolders. If you cannot find it then follow these steps....

1. Click ***file*** option [Click this image - 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HhLq.png)
2. Go to ***Preferences*** , then click ***settings*** [Click this image - 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sklkj.png)
3. Look for ***text editor***, then click ***files*** Scroll down to check ***.git*** in ***Exclude***

section. [Click this image - 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwZv0.png)

4. If ***.git*** is present, then remove it.
5. Now you will find .git folder in your main or sub folder....delete it  and upload the folder to GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

1 Firstly do "Remove-Item -Recurse -Force .\.git" command  in PowerShell
(without quotation) in the folder which is showing arrow. It will recursively delete the .git folder which contains all git related files and folder.

2. git init.
3. git add .
4. git commit -m "making folder available"
5. git push

Answer (score 0):

**THIS WORKED FOR ME !!**

1. Go to your project folder.
2. Go to **"View"** from the nav bar, go to **"Show"** and check **"Hidden Items"**.
3. Delete all the **".git"** folders from your project.
4. Initialize new or existing repo again and push your code.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7Qsj.png)

Try to delete this local folder and re-add your repository.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).