# GIT: with CRA app in your rootfolder, how can I push to git correctly?

Tags: git, github, git-remote

I am quite new to git. it might be a stupid question but I really don't know how to solve this problem.. I have been trying to find the answer but I couldn't...

I was trying to create my project using React.js and Node.js. I created my sever.js and client folder that is created from 'npx create-react-app client'. 
when I first pushed to git, I had this error message.

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

when I force-pushed it, it just went through and I found my client folder is not pushed to git at all, it is just empty in the repo. also, I noticed there was .git folder in client folder.(did not know cra app comes with .git file)

in client folder, I typed on command line (I googled and i found this command will undo .git init)

```
rm -rf .git
```

after this, I dont get the error message but still I cannot push client folder to git, the folder is still empty in the repo.

Also, the image of client folder in the repo is different then others. there is an arrow in the folder, the other folder does not have an arror in it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ62H.jpg)

client folder is cra app and src folder has server side codes.

how can I push my code to git correctly??

Comment: Did you try `git pull` as suggested? Have you `git add`ed the client folder?

Comment: yes, I tried but it did not work.. I still can't add the client folder.
but i solved the problem with the answer @VonC

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need first to remove the **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** ([special entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309) recording the tree SHA1 of the [nested git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62057615/6309) for the `client` folder)

```
git rm --cached client # no trailing /: not client/, just client
```

Then you can (since you have removed the `client/.git` subfolder), add client (`git add client`), commit and push.

Comment: thank you so much! I ran 'git rm --cached client' and I can push now!

Comment: @sooparookie Well done! Removing the `.git` subfolder was only one of the two steps necessary to "unregister" that nested Git repository.