# Are Repos in Azure DevOps not able to display git submodules?

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-submodules

In GitHub, when I have repo that contains a git submodule, the submodule is a link to the referenced git repo.

Now I have Azure DevOps there is no link, when I click on the submodule at least it shows the commit ID. Am I missing something? or is the User Experience really that bad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I have Azure DevOps there is no link, when I click on the
>   submodule at least it shows the commit ID. Am I missing something? or
>   is the User Experience really that bad?

Sorry but for now submodule link is **not supported**.

I agree that the submodule link is a good idea, so I just opened a feature request ticket [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1079757/azure-devops-repos-should-support-submodule-link.html) for you.

Please vote for it and track the update there. If it gets enough votes, the Product team would consider it seriously. Sorry for any inconvenience and thanks for your enthusiasm for our product.

Comment: Thanks :) Really hope the feature can come true since github supports the similar behavior.

Answer (score 1):

> there is no link,

Check first if your Azure DevOps Git repository includes a `.gitmodules`.

If it does not, then what you see is just a **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** ([special entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309) recording the tree SHA1 of a [nested git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62057615/6309))

Comment: repo contains .gitmodules