# Client folder in my react app isnt adding when trying to push and nothing is being pushed to github

Tags: reactjs, github

I created a react app on an express server and it seems that none of the client folder is being pushed to github correctly, I have no idea why it wont add when I run git add . and push it.

Comment: Check your .gitignore file

Comment: I dont have a .gitignore file in the root, the one in the client folder looks fine. is there something I should be looking for?

Comment: Why dont you post your folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the client folder has a .git subfolder in it: that would make it a [nested repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62057615/6309), in which case you would only push a [gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309) ([special entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309) in your index), instead of the folder *content*.

If you don't need the history of that client folder (just its file), you could simply rename or delete that nested `.git` folder, and then the add/commit/push would actually include the client folder files.