# How can I delete a repository on github with an arrow?

Tags: git, github

When it is a normal directory, I can delete it through the Github visual interface, but when there is an arrow in the repository, it doesn't work.

[image]

I would not like to delete my last commit. How do I do this in the Github interface?

Comment: Look into `revert` command of git

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An arrow means "**[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**", a SHA1 reference to another repository.
If you have a `.gitmodules` file in the same repository, that folder would have a '@': submodule, but I suspect it is not the case here.

A gitlink is not a folder, but a [special entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309) in the index, recording the tree SHA1 of a [nested repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62057615/6309).

It is best deleted locally:

```
git clone
git rm --cached algortimos-eleicao # no trailing /
git commit -m "remove gitlink"
git push
```

That will create a new commit which only remove that "folder".
(`git revert` does not necessarily work here, since I don't know what your last commit was)