# Github file not clickable

Tags: reactjs, github

I seem to run across an issue where my client folder is unclickable.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check in your local clone is the client folder has itself a `.git` subfolder: that would make it  a [nested repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62057615/6309), which means the chat-app repository only records a [gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309) ([special entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309) named here "`client`" in your index), instead of the folder *content*.

If you don't need the history of that `client` folder (just its file), you could simply rename or delete that nested `.git` folder, and then the add/commit/push would actually include the client folder files.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: Open visual studio code in your project folder.

Step 2: Then go to File > Prefernces > settings > Text Editor > Files.

Step 3: Scroll down your cursor till "Exclude".Delete .git Item from there.

Step 4: Now you can see the hidden .git file in your folder structure. Delete it from there.  After that it will work .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).