# Why is my folder not present on remote main branch?

Tags: git

I am trying to commit and push my repo from VSC to github. I managed to push my remote repo using command `git push --set-upstream origin main`, however, when I check my repo on Github, I realised the server folder is clickable but the client folder isn't.
[image]

I checked `git status` for both my server and client directories, and found that my server and parent folder(containing both server and client) are on branch `main` but my client folder is on branch `master`.

I also checked `git remote -v` for all 3 directories and they all have the same origin.

Can someone advise as to why my client folder isn't pushed to github successfully?

Comment: Maybe you have another Git repository inside one of these directories?

Comment: Are you saying that your `main` branch doesn't contain the `client` folder?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62972287/github-file-not-clickable

Comment: The icon left of client makes me believe that this is actually a submodule