# .gitignore Comes up when i copy my .git Folders into another folder?

Tags: github

.gitignore comes up and doesn't allow me to upload my second project into the GitHub.

this is a tree of my codes :

-src -> backend ->[.gitignore , djangoproject]
-src -> frontend ->[.gitignore  , gui]

so when I push all the folders into Github, .gitignore error comes up
so what can I be doing?

Comment: did you add the Frontend files to your git repository?

Comment: Ui is a *submodule*, it's a separate repo.

Comment: Read the answers on the linked duplicate, they give you various options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may happen for several reasons:

1st verify whether you have added the fronend files to your repository or not

2nd check your `.gitignore` file (if there is any)

Comment: sorry where is the .gitignore !?

Comment: have you created .gitignore file? just check using ctrl+h (linux) . any files added in .gitignore will be ignored to push on remote repo. 

if there is no .gitignore file. just try `git push` again adding all files using command `git add --all` and push to remote repo after committing your changes.

Comment: additionally check the answer of this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62056294/github-folders-have-a-white-arrow-on-them

Answer (score 0):

If there are no files in the directory git will not stage the directory when you run `git add`. Git does not care about files and directories, it tracks content changes.

UPDATE

If you use submodules (repository inside repository) read this: http://blog.joncairns.com/2011/10/how-to-use-git-submodules/