# Can't upload client-side part on github

Tags: github

I have project that I want to upload on github. It has client side with react and server side. I've uploaded my project but I can't open client folder. What's wrong with it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmOBW.png

Comment: Please provide more information, for instance, tell what commands you used to upload your project to git.

Comment: I used the same command as I usually use: git push -u origin master

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62056294/github-folders-have-a-white-arrow-on-them Check if this helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub folders have a white arrow on them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62056294/github-folders-have-a-white-arrow-on-them)