# Folders not pushed to Git remote repository

Tags: git, github, git-push

I am trying to push my project folder to my repository on GitHub. The project has two separate folders, one for back end and one for front end. I gave the following commands from the main folder which contains these folders:

```
git init
git add .
git commit
git remote add origin https://github.com/<reponame>/Todo.git
git push -u origin master
```

The push was successful. It didn't give any errors.
upon `git status` it shows,

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

But when I go to my repo, I could only see my back-end folder and its contents. The front-end folder icon appears with a arrow mark, but it has no content.

What could be wrong? How do I push both the folders together? Attached image for reference. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzWsq.png)Please help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfnPP.png)

Comment: front-end directory has files inside? If there are no files yet, git won't care for it.

Comment: `git add --all` rather than `git add .`. `--all` adds new untracked files too.

Comment: @VincentRamdhanie Thanks I tried git add * and and pushed to remote. It worked.

Comment: @eftshift0 yes it had files inside.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub folders have a white arrow on them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62056294/github-folders-have-a-white-arrow-on-them)

Answer (score 0):

> git add .

will add any changes from the current folder.

> git add --all

will add any changes from your repository

Answer (score 0):

git init

git add *

git commit

git remote add origin https://github.com//Todo.git

git push -u origin master

// this worked for me //