# Error with pushing to Github, how do I solve this?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git, github

I push a repo containing 2 folders - a Nodejs backend and a react client. On push, I would notice that the client frontend isn't highlightable. It would show an arrow instead.

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub folders have a white arrow on them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62056294/github-folders-have-a-white-arrow-on-them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you have nested git repositories. They are called *Git submodules*. Your folder structure look like this:

```
.
├── .git
├── client
│   └── .git
└── backend
```

If you want to keep everything under one repository, with no Git submodules, you can simply delete `client/.git`.