# How do I fix the white arrow on the folder thing on GitHub even after deleting the .git folder?

Tags: git

I recently made the mistake of pushing to my repository while having a `.git` folder inside another folder. Doing so has resulted in unclickable folders with white arrows on them on my GitHub repository. Clicking on the commit message shows `Submodule XYZ added at abc123`.

I've proceeded to go into that folder and do `rm -rf .git`, but I'm unable to undo the process.

I've taken a look at [this other relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62056294/github-folders-have-a-white-arrow-on-them) and did what is suggested, but the proposed solutions don't seem to apply to my case.

Does anyone know how I may be able to undo this? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should:

- `git rm --cached afolder` (no trailing slash), with '`aFolder`' being the name of the folder in which there was a `.git/` subfolder (that you already removed)
- commit (git commit -m "remove nested Git repository reference")
- add (`git add aFolder`)
- commit again (`git commit -m "Import aFolder content"`)
- and push

You should now see `aFolder` content in your GitHub repository.