# After pushing my file to Git-Hub with REACT IT IS NOT OPENING

Tags: reactjs, github

[image]

After adding my file (React) to git -hub it is not opening. I attached file which id after adding what is showing.

Comment: By attaching did you mean you committed the file? ` it is not opening` opening where? In browser?

Comment: Thank your for your comment.  yes , i  pushed , and committed all file. but it has arrow on the file  as you see in photo. I could not open it

Comment: For one thing it looks like your repo is set up wrongly, the directory that's presumably your whole app is a *submodule*: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62056294/3001761.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub folders have a white arrow on them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62056294/github-folders-have-a-white-arrow-on-them)

Comment: thank you for your comment @jonsharpe . I checked  this attached article,  as explanation i found hidden file.  maybe the reason is this one