# When I push to GitHub I can't open the assignment folder

Tags: github

I was able to push my assignment to GitHub, but I am unable to open it

Here is what I see on GitHub after the push:

[image: GitHub]

Comment: Is your `assignment` folder a symbolic link (I see a right arrow on the logo)?

Answer (score 0):

Check first if assignment, on your local computer, has a `.git` subfolder in it.
That would make it a [nested Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62057615/6309) inside your main repository, and pushing it would only push a [gitlink entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309) (a [special entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309) in the index)

Ideally, each of those folders would need to be pushed in their own matching Git repositories.