# Git uploading inaccessible files to github

Tags: git

After adding, committing, and uploading to Git, I am unable to open the file on GitHub, as it's not allowing me to click on it. Please let me  know what could be issue and how to rectify this.

[image: Issue Files in GitHub]

Comment: Does this answer your question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62056294/github-folders-have-a-white-arrow-on-them

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub folders have a white arrow on them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62056294/github-folders-have-a-white-arrow-on-them)

Comment: Yes this answers my question, thanks