# Unable to open folders in GitHub

Tags: github

I pushed a commit on my remote GitHub repo and it appears like this:

[image]

In the above screenshot, the top 2 directories appear with a special symbol and strangely I can't click on it or open it. Whereas I can click and open other folder. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub folders have a white arrow on them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62056294/github-folders-have-a-white-arrow-on-them)

Answer (score 0):

The icon is for submodules. Git also doesn't track folders as such. Do you have another .git inside that folder where you have initialised git by mistake?

More verbose explanation of submodules.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62057615/12040634