# React project difficulties to push on GitHub

Tags: reactjs, git

I am using an iMac of 2011 and Visual Studio Code (same issue in PyCharm).

I pushed an Django and React project to GitHub. The Django project is pushed like expected. The React part of the project is really strange. The folder is not clickable. [GitHub repo picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKDQ1.png)

I checked in VSC in terminal `git status`:

```
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
(use “git add < file>…” to update what will be committed)
(use “git restore < file>…” to discard changes in working directory)
(commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
modified: .DS_Store
modified: frontend (modified content, untracked content)

no changes added to commit (use “git add” and/or “git commit -a”)
```

If I try to `git add .` it tells me at `git status`:

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
(use “git restore --staged < file>…” to unstage)
modified: .DS_Store

Changes not staged for commit:
(use “git add < file>…” to update what will be committed)
(use “git restore< file>…” to discard changes in working directory)
(commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
**modified: frontend (modified content, untracked content)**
```

I created in PyCharm just a Django and React project and wanted to push the project to a repo on GitHub. Before I pushed the code the terminal of PyCharm showed me:

[PyCharm terminal picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35Slk.png)

If I try `git submodule add <url of rep> react_frontend` it tells me that the react_frontend folder is already connected to the repo.

Is that now the new way of pushing to GitHub or what can I do to get the React folder to my GitHub account?

Previous, one month ago, I was capable of pushing a React-Django-Project to GitHub without any issues... Thanks

------- EDIT ----
[picture of the React folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXeFu.png)

Comment: Do you have a nested `.git` folder in the react project?

Comment: [That's not a folder, that's a *submodule*.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62056294/1256452)

Comment: to @MattD.Webb:  no, there is no `.git` folder just a `.gitignore`. will upload a picture of the React folder in my post above

Comment: @torek: thanks for that link. I will check this link put later

Comment: The error message suggests there is another git repo, make sure you’ve got hidden folders shown.

Comment: @MattD.Webb and @torek: Of course there is the `.git` file (a hidden file...) when displaying the hidden files in Finder I was able to see it. I will delete the `.git` folder and push again.   OR can I add the repo name inside somewhere in that `.git` folder to connect the React folder to the "correct" repo?

Comment: display the hidden files on Mac in Finder: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5870/how-to-show-hidden-files-and-folders-in-finder

Comment: Make sure you remove the correct one. The .git folder should be at the root so any nested ones should be removed to the correctly track the full project.

Comment: Thanks Matt. That was really helpful. Done. Awesome! Thanks to Torek too.

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your frontend folder there is another `.git` file locally.
Remove those so it will track the folder. But keep in mind, that all the node modules will upload to you repo. Repo size will increase.

```
rm .git
cd ..
git rm --cache client_folder
```