# How do I commit a FullStack app to GitHub?

Tags: node.js, git, express, github, react-fullstack

Trying to add a fullstack app to GitHub. In the root I have a client directory (React) and a server directory (Node/Express) and a README.md

When I try git init this and send them to GitHub the Client folder gets an arrow inside of it I cant click it or view it on Github how do I fix this?

This is the arrow on the client folder basically this image:

[image]

Comment: Files are files. Without more details it'll be difficult to help.

Comment: remove the `.git` from the client directory, nested git's are treated as submodules

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62056294/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+white+arrow

Answer (score 0):

> nested git's are treated as submodules

Not quite, only as gitlinks (reference to a tree SHA1 in the index of the parent repository)

If it was a submodule, the white arrow folder would actually be a link, to the remote submodule repository.

If it is not a link, then, as commented, removing the nested repo .git/ subfolder, adding and committing the folder content, and pushing will be enough.