# Recover removed local folder using git

Tags: git, github, github-pages, github-for-windows, angular-cli-ghpages

I made an Angular project and pushed it on github ( I don't know much about git ). After pushing, I saw there was just one folder with a right arrow on it and when clicking on it didn't result in anything.
So I thought of removing it and pushing it again.
So, by using internet, I found this code.

`git rm -rf folder-name`

Using this, the original folder from local was deleted and now here I am panicking how I can recover that back.

Any help and suggestions would be helpful plz.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what you mean is:

> When I go to GitHub and view the commit, I see this icon: [image: folder with a white arrow on it]

what it means is that you committed a "naked" *gitlink*, i.e., a reference to some other Git repository.  This is half of a *submodule:* a submodule is a reference to some other Git repository that includes the instructions that Git needs to *clone* that other Git repository.

Removing the gitlink and committing merely made a *new* commit in which there is no gitlink any more.  This did not damage anything.  All *new* commits merely *add on* to your existing repository; the old commits continue to exist.  Checking out the older commit, or using `git revert` to back out the changes made by a commit you dislike, will "undo" that effect.

The key difference between checking out an old commit and using `git revert` is that the former simply *gets you the old commit*, as a "detached HEAD".  You can work with it, and even create a new branch from this point if you like.  Using `git revert` tells Git: *make another, even-newer commit that undoes the effect of some previous commit*.  That is, instead of going back in time, you go forward in time but put things back.  One method is vaguely analogous to "Gosh, I broke my vase, let me go back in time to before I broke it" and the other is "Gosh, I broke my vase, let me glue it back together".

You almost never want to have a "naked" gitlink.  Whether you want to have a real submodule, or just incorporate some other Git repository's currently-checked-out-files into a *new* commit in *this* repository, is another question entirely.  There are more details at [GitHub folders have a white arrow on them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62056294/1256452).

Comment: After my first commit only I got the naked folder. And then I run the rm -rf command which removed the folder from the local. Now I don't have any access to that folder anywhere.

Comment: It's still in the old commits. New commits *add*. Even if you remove every file and commit, you've just *added* things. Going back to the old commit gets the files back.