# Unnacessible file on github with left arrow icon

Tags: git, github

I got two folders [image]server and client that I want to publish to github at first I published the client folder without the server , I deleted the repo and then when back to the main folder and uploaded it to github now the client folder has a left arrow icon and can't be clicked or accessed

[image: Folders]

[image: Github Folder]

Comment: Does the following URL solve your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62057615/3653544

Comment: It worked I followed the top answer second step which is deleting the hidden .git file from client folder thank you