# A file is not accessible on GitHub , it has an arrow on it. How can I open it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github

This is the link to the project.
This is my first React Project.

https://github.com/yash251/first-react-app

How can I access the files inside my arrow folder ?

Answer (score 0):

[GitHub folders have a white arrow on them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62056294/github-folders-have-a-white-arrow-on-them)

Seems to be the same issue, feel free to come back if you don't find what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar problem here [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62056294/github-folders-have-a-white-arrow-on-them)
I see that you have deleted a subfolder here, maybe try going back to that commit

---

[Commit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0nth.png)

---