# Adding README pointer in Github

Tags: github, markdown, readme

So im trying to do something similiar to what vercel does with their README.
[image: vercel's readme]

When I go into the raw code its just the path to the referenced readme

```
packages/next/README.md
```

So I attempted to do this with my own repo and was given back

```
packages/repo name here/README.md
```

at the front of my github page.

Anyone know how to do what vercel does?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62056294/3001761

Comment: i dont understand... what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That symbol means that the readme directory is actually a [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules): a pointer to another git repository. You can't click on the link in github because it point at a repository that is not hosted on github.

the another documentation you can see reference in here about [blog sobmodules](https://github.blog/2016-02-01-working-with-submodules/)